# OpenCV python Bayer conversion error

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

The following code:

```
filePath = os.path.join(root,file)
image = cv2.imread(filePath)
convertedImage = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BAYER_GR2RGB)
```

Produces this error:

```
opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:4196: error: (-215) scn == 1 && dcn == 3 in function cv::cvtColor
```

What does this error mean (other than stating the number of channels in source and destination)? How can I fix this? Is it to do with the way I load the image?

Comment: imread() gives you a bgr, 3chan img. what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Convert bayer images to rgb images

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forget to specify the type of the input image to be read. By default, cv2.imread will read image with flag cv2.IMREAD_COLOR (as indicated in [their documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html)). You can change your code to the following:

```
filePath = os.path.join(root,file)
#Load the image as grayscale image
image = cv2.imread(filePath,0)
convertedImage = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BAYER_GR2RGB)
```